# How to center a Paypal button in IE8

Tags: css

On one of my pages, http://artistsatlaketahoe.com/abstract.html  , the Paypal buttons appear centered beneath text in FireFox and Chrome, but not in IE8. I got the centering to work in FF and Chrome by adding the following within the Paypal code snippet relating the Add to Cart image:

style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"

Unfortunately, it isn't working in IE8. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

give it a width to the button

Comment: Hey, adding the button width solved the problem. Thanks! 7 word solution!

Answer (score 1):

for IE the button needs to have a width, and the container for the button should have text-align:center; set.

```
/*Center the paypal button in IE*/
#paypal-button-container{
  text-align:center;
}
/*Center the button in modern browsers*/
#paypal-button{
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `align="left";`